# Getting certain information out of a text file

Tags: c#, regex

I have a ~7mb text file that I want to extract some information from and it contains many instances of similar format to:

```
            "name": "Riki's Dagger",
            "defindex": 0,
            "item_class": "dota_item_wearable",
            "item_type_name": "#DOTA_WearableType_Daggers",
            "item_name": "#DOTA_Item_Rikis_Dagger",
            "proper_name": false,
            "item_quality": 0,
            "image_inventory": null,
            "min_ilevel": 1,
            "max_ilevel": 1,
            "image_url": "",
            "image_url_large": "",
```

I want to extract the name and defindex, check that this instance does/doesn't contain some keywords and then place it in a new text file so that I can use it later.
My plan was to search the file for each instance of "name" (with quotations), and set all contents before the next instance of "name" to a variable called current. Then from there search the current string for the information that I needed. Is that the best way to do it and how would I go about it? Should I be using Regex or is the file too large? Some direction would be much appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            string ingameschemaFilePath = @"C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\SteamBot\Bin\Debug\ingameschema.txt";
            string dota2schemaFilePath = @"C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\SteamBot\Bin\Debug\dota2schema.txt";
            string schemaFilePath = @"C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\SteamBot\Bin\Debug\schema.txt";

            string[] ingameschema = File.ReadAllLines(ingameschemaFilePath);
            string[] dota2schema = File.ReadAllLines(dota2schemaFilePath);
            string[] current = null;
            string[] name = null;
            string[] defindex = null;
            string[] rarity = null;

            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(schemaFilePath))
            {
                foreach (//search for "name"->"name" segment here)
                {
                    //    if current.Contains("dota_item_wearable") == false, current.Contains("announcer", "courier", "ward", "egg", "costume", "HUD", "smeevil", "taunt", "bait", "lure", "bundle" ) == true, 
                    //          break
                    }
                }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think you could show us the beginning, and the end of that file? I have a feeling this is JSON, in which case you may have a much better option than Regex.

Comment: It looks a bit like JSON, but without the braces {}. Is the input file actual JSON, or is it just a long list without separation for each item element? If it's JSON, there are several great libraries that will parse the file into neat objects for you. I'm a fan of JSON.NET myself, but there are other good ones.

Comment: Start:
{
 "result": {
  "status": 1,
  "items_game_url": "http:\/\/media.steampowered.com\/apps\/570\/scripts\/items\/items_game.***************.txt",
  "qualities": {
   "normal": 0,
   "genuine": 1,
   "vintage": 2,
   "unusual": 3,
   "unique": 4,
   "community": 5,
   "developer": 6,
   "selfmade": 7,
   "customized": 8,
   "strange": 9,
   "completed": 10,
   "haunted": 11,
   "tournament": 12,
   "favored": 13

Comment: Well, if that's no JSON.

Comment: And reading a this large JSON will cost some memory issues.

Comment: JSON is lighter weight than XML if I am not mistaken so I do not think that will cause any `Memory Issues` explain how you come up with that assumption `Hemant_Negi`

Comment: yes i know, but in Question he is saying that file is ~7mb and don't you think storing 7mb in memory is a bad idea.

Comment: 7mb is nothing, now 7GB that's a whole different story..

Comment: Thanks, I beleive it is json format. I will go look up Json Deserialzing, and get back to you all.

Comment: yes @user2688799 it will be a good idea, i think u should try both options and check which is more effecient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `StreamReader` to read line by line from the text file and then find the desired info in that line.

There is only a problem if you're storing a portions of the file until you finish reading it, then you can run into memory issues (but you'd be surprised how large you can let Lists & Dictionaries get before you run out of memory)

What you need to do is save your processed data as soon as you can, and not keep it in memory (or keep as little in memory as possible).

Comment: Why would he want to do that when .NET has Deserializer's designed to help you do that when working with JSON

Comment: @DJKRAZE i guess u are right 7mb is not much data, but still there will be some limit applied in this kind of cases.

Comment: I would suggest reading up on `JSON` I am not sure how you are coming up with these untested assumptions sorry

Answer (score 0):

One approach you might consider is to put source into some kind of dictionary based collection that you can then address by the keys your interested in for that item.

Example

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourcefile = @"C:\test\source.txt";
        string outputfile = @"C:\test\output.txt";

        string[] source = File.ReadAllLines(sourcefile);

        // The list would represent the collection of all the items 
        List<NameValueCollection> list = new List<NameValueCollection>();

        // Each nvc would represent the collection of attributes for that item
        NameValueCollection nvc = null;

        foreach (string s in source)
        {
            //Split your string into its key and value
            string[] nv = s.Split(':');

            //If the key is name you have finished your previous item, and will it to the list and start a new one
            if (nv[0] == "name")
            {
                if (nvc != null)
                    list.Add(nvc);

                nvc = new NameValueCollection();
            }
            // Add your attribute and value to the items attribute collection
            nvc.Add(nv[0], nv[1]);
        } 
    }
```

7mb is a little large but with today's memory you should be fine.  If it becomes an issue you might consider using ReadLine from the Stream object instead which will load each line into memory one at a time.

Let me know if this helps at all.